# Check AD Site Existence

Tags: arrays, powershell, csv, foreach, sites

I would like to import sites in my Active Directory environment with a CSV containing sitenames:

Example of my CSV-input:

```
New York
Dallas
New Jersey
```

I want to make a script that checks the existence of the sites first before the actual creation process occurs. However, I'm having some trouble with checking the input of 2 arrays:

```
#Clear process
$ADsites = ""
$SitesFilter = ""
$CSV = ""

[array] $ADSites = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Forest]::GetCurrentForest().Sites 

$csv=Import-Csv c:\sites.csv -header "Site"

#Filtering the Sitenames
Foreach ($ADSite in $ADSites) {
    [array] $SitesFilter += $ADSite.Name
}

$CSV | Foreach-Object {
    if (??? -eq $_.Site) {
        Write-Host "Site" $_.Site "already exists" 
    } else {
        Write-Host "Site" $_.Site "is not found"
    }
}
```

How can I compare the content of the array `$SitesFilter` with the sitenames in the CSV-file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope below script could help, you should use `-in`, which could tell if object is within an array

```
[array] $ADSites = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Forest]::GetCurrentForest().Sites 

$csv=Import-Csv c:\sites.csv -header "Site"

#Get an site name string array
$SitesFilter = @($ADSites | %{"$($_.Name)"}) 

$CSV | Foreach-Object {
    if ($SitesFilter -contains $_.Site ){
                Write-Host "Site $($_.Site) already exists" 
    } Else { Write-Host "Site $($_.Site) is not found" }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, however im getting the following error. It seems like the -in parameter is not recognized --> Unexpected token 'in' in expression or statement.
At line:9 char:18

Comment: The -in start from powershell 3.0.

Comment: @C.B. Thanks, I tried to avoid new syntax but forget this one.

Answer (score 0):

```
$array1 = '1','2','3'
$array2 = '2','3','4'
compare $array1 $array2
get-help compare-object -full
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

[BobLobLaw's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15319585/1630171) has an interesting idea, but is unfortunately far too incomplete to be of actual use. I see 2 issues with it:

- `Import-Csv` produces an array of custom objects, whereas the OP's `$SitesFilter` is an array of strings. `Compare-Object` will always report every item as different unless the compared items are of the same type.
- `Compare-Object` will report differences on both sides, i.e. sites that don't exist in AD as well as sites that do exist in AD but are not listed in the CSV. If the OP wants only sites that don't already exist in AD he'll have to filter the output by `SideIndicator`. However, you can't expand `InputObject` and `SideIndicator` at the same time with `select -Expand`.

Something like this might do the trick:

```
$csv = Import-Csv "c:\sites.csv" -Header "Site" | % { $_.Site }

compare $csv $SitesFilter | ? {
  (select -Input $_ -Expand SideIndicator) -eq "<="
} | select -Expand InputObject
```

For reporting which site does or doesn't exist something like this might do:

```
compare $csv $SitesFilter | % {
  if ( (select -Input $_ -Expand SideIndicator) -eq "<=" ) {
    "Site '{0}' doesn't exist." -f (select -Input $_ -Expand InputObject)
  } else {
    "Site '{0}' already exists." -f (select -Input $_ -Expand InputObject)
  }
}
```

Or one could `select` the information into custom objects:

```
$site   = { select -Input $_ -Expand InputObject }
$exists = { (select -Input $_ -Expand SideIndicator) -ne "<=" }

compare $csv $SitesFilter `
  | select @{n='Site';e=$site},@{n='Exists';e=$exists} `
  | % {
    if ( $_.Exists ) {
      "Site '{0}' exists." -f $_.Site
    } else {
      "Site '{0}' doesn't exist." -f $_.Site
    }
  }
```